# Mpdf is not showing "₹" currency text

Tags: codeigniter, currency, mpdf

I am using Mpdf version 5.7.4 in CodeIgnitor. Mpdf is not showing "₹" currency text in generated PDF  It shows block instead. All other currency displays properly.
I am attaching the output of the generated pdf file.
[PDF Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCpPC.png)

Comment: I'm not seeing any output of the generated pdf file.
What is the font that you are using? I'd assume the problem is not within Mpdf but the font.

Comment: Please see the attached image. Yes I have added RupeeForadian.ttf file in config_fornts.php, but still "₹" currency text is not loading. Let me know if I need to do any other configuration also.  @renegade999